# How to know which data has been changed in an array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, watch

I'm trying to get which data has been changed in array. my use case is First time all data fetch from ajax and show within row and fetch new data using $http every 5 second. I need to know that if the new data is same as old one. If yes then which value has changed so I've to update that  background to some color..

What I've already tried

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('listingController', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

        $scope.listings;

        setInterval(function(){ 
            $http.get('_includes/ajax.php?req=get').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.listings = data;
                  console.log(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  // log error
            }); 

        }, 5000);

    });

    app.controller('RentalDateController', function($scope, $log){

         console.log($scope.listings);
         $scope.$watch('listings.Third_Column', function (Third_Column, oldvalue) {
            //$log.info(Third_Column, $scope.listings.First_Column);
             console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldvalue, 'newValue:', Third_Column);
          }, true);
    });
```

My html is

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="listingController">


    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Testing</th>
            <th>Pripse</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="row in listings" ng-controller="RentalDateController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.Third_Column">
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.First_Column">
            <th>{{row.Third_Column}}</th>
            <th>{{row.First_Column}}</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I think I need to use $watch but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the angular two-way data binding so it should automatically update your ng-repeat when the model changes.

I suggest the following 
1) Remove RentalDate controller first. 
2) Use $timeout, and on success of http use this

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.listing = data;
});
```

If that doesn't still automatically update, put the array in an object.

```
$scope.data = {}
$scope.data.listings = putArrayHere();
```

This will work because of this. Read up. :D

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance

Comment: Mine code already updating DOM. I Just need that if some values has changed in array that result <td> background will be green. suppose on first time fetching one property value is 9 and after the second time fetching that value has changed to 10 so I need to show that <td> property background to green

Comment: I see, sorry I was answering this at around 2am. Well, what you can do is first follow what I said to cleanup your code and then do the same approach as @Anubhav, but first, create an object array that has a name and a flag like  { name: 'foo', isNew:'true' } then go through the array and replace row.Third_column with the object when you find something that's not the same as your old one change the flag. Now you have a customized $scope.listing... you can put ng-class="'make-green' : row.Third_Column.isNew" and write the css approriately.

Comment: Btw, you should loop through all the value and check the equality manually when you receive the array. There's no quicker way than this but this way its only BigTheta(n) runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('listingController', function($scope, $http, $timeout){

        $scope.listings;
        var previousListing = [];
        var newData;

        setInterval(function(){ 
            $http.get('_includes/ajax.php?req=get').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.listings = data;
                  console.log(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  // log error
            });

            if( previousListing.length == $scope.listings.length )
            {
                console.log('No new data available.');
            }
            else
            {
                // length of the arrays are different, hence new data must be available
                console.log('New data available!');
                newData = $scope.listings.splice( 0, ($scope.listings.length - previousListing.length) ); // returns new data in the form of an array
                console.log(newData);
                previousListing = $scope.listings; // reset previous data variable

            }

        }, 5000);

    });
```

Comment: It's always showing 'New data available!' and I still don't get the values which has been changed. What I want is this. Once the value has been changed the <td> has green background for some seconds.